# Python: how to use a custom font from google drive in kivy labels without storing it locally

Tags: python, fonts, permissions, kivy, label

I want to run the kivy app in a python emulator on android without all files access, so i need it to not be stored locally

I tried using io bytes, requests, etc, all to no avail.

It would be great if someone could help me with how i could do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom font from Google Drive in Kivy labels without storing it locally can be challenging because Kivy typically requires fonts to be locally accessible but you can try this methode:

1. Host your custom font file on Google Drive and ensure that the sharing settings are set to "Anyone with the link can view."
2. Obtain the direct download link for the font file from Google Drive. You can do this by right-clicking on the file, selecting "Get shareable link," and modifying the link to make it a direct download link. It should look something like this:

   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID
3. Request library will download font from google drive.
4. **kivy.core.text.LabelBase.register()** will load your font which is downloaded right now.

```html
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
import requests
from io import BytesIO

class CustomFontApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Replace with your Google Drive font file link
        font_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID"
        
        # Download the font file
        response = requests.get(font_url)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Load the font file
            font_data = BytesIO(response.content)
            LabelBase.register("CustomFont", fn_regular=font_data)
            
            # Create a label using the custom font
            label = Label(text="Hello, Custom Font!", font_name="CustomFont", font_size="30sp")
            return label
        else:
            return Label(text="Font download failed.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomFontApp().run()
```

Comment: I got the error:       font = resource_find(font_type)
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/resources.py", line 52, in resource_find
     if filename[:8] == 'atlas://':
 TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object is not subscriptable

Comment: from kivy.resources import resource_add_path

# Assuming your font files are located in '/path/to/fonts'
resource_add_path('/path/to/fonts')